# Provide Authentication for Spring Cloud Config (Github Repo for Config Files)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config-server

I've uploaded all to the properties to github (as central config repo) and I've made a spring boot application for Config Server. I'm getting error for Authentication. How can I do the authentication or provide credentials?

Config Sever application.properties file :

```
spring.application.name=ConfigServer
server.port=1111

#spring.profiles.active=native
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/<USERNAME>/msp1-config
```

Added @EnableConfigServer annotation to Main Application.

When I'm trying to run it and make a get request using postman:

```
http://localhost:1111/application/default
```

Console Error :

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/ParundeepSingh/msp1-config: Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:254) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:306) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:200) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.cloneToBasedir(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:612) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.copyRepository(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:587) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.createGitClient(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:570) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.refresh(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:267) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.getLocations(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:245) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.getLocations(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:139) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.findOne(AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.java:55) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.findOne(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:173) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.CompositeEnvironmentRepository.findOne(CompositeEnvironmentRepository.java:64) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentEncryptorEnvironmentRepository.findOne(EnvironmentEncryptorEnvironmentRepository.java:61) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.getEnvironment(EnvironmentController.java:131) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.defaultLabel(EnvironmentController.java:108) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframew ........
```

Comment: Is your git repo secured?

Comment: Yeah, it is. But when I tried to make my repo public. It works fine. Is there any way by which we can access private repos ?

Comment: There are username and password properties to set